# How-To update HomePod firmware without direct connection to the internet?

Tags: security, firmware, homepod

The Homepod has no connection to the internet, however my iPhone has a 5G internet connection. How do I update the HomePod via iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HomePod must be connected to the internet to update, since it performs the update internally. The update is not streamed from your iPhone to the HomePod.

You will need to find a way to connect the Wi-Fi network to the internet to perform an update.